# Чат на php и mysql

Tags: php, mysqli

Пишу чат на php, сообщения отправляются в базу данных mysql и получается достать их оттуда, но проблема в том, что не получается вывести email того человека, который пишет это сообщение. У меня 2 базы данных: одна для регистрации и авторизации, а другая для чата. После успешного логина юзер попадает на страницу чата, и когда пишет сообщение выводится его email на всех сообщениях, а мне нужно, чтобы только над его сообщениями выводилось его имя. Как это реализовать? Вот код логина:

```
<?php
session_start();
include 'db.php';
    if (isset($_POST['email-e']) && isset($_POST['password-pass'])) { 
    $email_e = mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli,$_POST['email-e']);
    $password_pass = md5(md5($_POST['password-pass']));

    $query = "SELECT id, email, password FROM users_data 
              WHERE email = '$email_e' AND password = '$password_pass'";
    $sql = mysqli_query($mysqli,$query) or die(mysqli_error());
    if (mysqli_num_rows($sql) == 1) {
        $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($sql);

    $_SESSION['user_id'] = $row['id'];
    $_SESSION['email-e'] = $row['email'];
  }
    else {
        echo 'User was not found!';
      header("Location: login.html"); 
    }
  }
    if (isset($_SESSION['email-e'])){
     header("Location: chat.php");
  } 
?>
```

А вот код чата:

```
<?php
session_start();
include 'db_chat.php';
// header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
//echo trim($_SESSION['email-e'])." <br />"."Вы авторизованы <br />";
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<title>Chat</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<title>Chat</title>
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lobster" rel="stylesheet">
<style>
 input{font:12px arial} a{color:#00f;text-decoration:none} a:hover{text-decoration:underline} #wrapper,#loginform{margin:0 auto;padding-bottom:25px;background:#ebf4fb;width:504px;border:1px solid #acd8f0}#loginform{padding-top:18px}#loginform p{margin:5px} #chatbox{text-align:left;margin:0 auto;margin-bottom:25px;padding:10px;background:#fff;height:270px;width:430px;border:1px solid #acd8f0;overflow:auto} #usermsg{width:380px;height:50px;border:1px solid #acd8f0;border-radius:3px 3px 3px 3px}#submitmsg{width:70px;height:53px;border-radius:5px 5px 5px 5px;cursor:pointer}.error{color:#f00} #menu{padding:12.5px 25px 12.5px 25px} .welcome{float:left} .logout{float:right} .msgln{margin:0 0 2px 0}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="menu">
        <p class="welcome" style="font-family: 'Lobster', cursive; font-size:1.1em;">Welcome, <?php echo trim($_SESSION['email-e'])?><b></b></p>
        <form  name="message" action="" method="post">
        <p class="logout" name="logout">
            <button name="exit" id="exit" href="login.php" style="cursor:pointer; border-radius:3px 3px 3px 3px; color:red;">Exit Chat</button>
        </p>
        </form>   
        <div style="clear:both"></div>
    </div>
    <div id="chatbox">
<?php
if(isset($_POST['submitmsg'])) {
    if(!empty($_POST['usermsg']) && is_string($_POST['usermsg'])) {

        $user_id = $_SESSION['user_id'];
        $username = $_SESSION['email-e'];
        $time =  date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
        $usermsg = trim($_POST['usermsg']);

        $sql_chat ="INSERT INTO users_chat (usermsg,user_id,time) 
                    VALUES('{$usermsg}','{$user_id}','{$time}')";

        $res = mysqli_query($mysqli_chat,$sql_chat);
    } 
}
        $query_chat = "SELECT * FROM `users_chat`";
        $res = mysqli_query($mysqli_chat,$query_chat);

        while($row_chat = mysqli_fetch_array($res)) {

            $query_chat ="SELECT * FROM `users_chat`";
            $user_id = $row_chat['user_id'];
            print '<div>';

            echo  'Email:'.$row_chat['user_id'].'<br>';
            print 'Time:'.' '.$row_chat['time'].'<br>';
            print htmlspecialchars($row_chat['usermsg']).'<br><br>';
            print '</div>';
        }

        // if(isset($_POST['exit'])) {
        //     unset($_SESSION['user_id']);
        //     session_destroy();
        //     header("Location: login.html");
        // }
?>
</div>
<form  name="message"   action="" method="post">
<input name="usermsg"   type="text"   id="usermsg" style="margin-left:25px;">
<input name="submitmsg" type="submit" id="submitmsg" value="Send" style="cursor:pointer; color:green;"/><br>
</form>    
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

База данных чата работает, все подключается. Вот ее структура:

```
CREATE TABLE `users_chat` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `username` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `usermsg` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `user_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `time` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Comment: Надеюсь "разными базами данных" вы все таки называете разные таблицы в одной базе. Вам надо почитать про join https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_(SQL) И просто при выборке join'ить две таблицы

Comment: @Mike Да, одна таблица users, а в ней users_data и users_chat. Я делал  помощью INNER JOIN, но он просто объединил их в одну таблицу, но все осталось также. Вот так SELECT * 
FROM users_chat INNER JOIN users_data 
ON users_chat.user_id = users_data.id;

Comment: правильно. И в этой выборке у вас у каждого сообщения есть имя того, кто его написал (кстати, вместо `*` стоит явно перечислять поля, которые вам нужны). А дальше уже задача логики на php решить в каких случаях имя показывать, а в каких нет. Например сверив имя или id с текущим пользователем

Comment: @Mike вот и я про то, но у меня не выходит снова. может написать как нужно сделать? я прописывал этот код в phpmyadmin в консоли

Comment: Так вы этот запрос с join пишите не в phpmyadmin, а у себя в скрипте, вместо того, который сейчас сообщения выводит.

Comment: P.S. а еще попробуйте в чате написать сообщение с одинарной кавычкой. У вас при этом все сломается. потому что нельзя текст переменных непосредственно подставлять в текст запроса. надо пользоваться подготавливаемыми выражениями и привязкой значений. http://php.net/manual/ru/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php

Comment: @Mike вы имеете виду написать это все вместо моего $query_chat?

Comment: БД вам позволяет достать именно то, что требуется. Вот и пользуйтесь этой возвожностью. сначала в phpmyadmin пишете запрос, который вернет именно те данные которые вам нужны. А потом переносите этот запрос к себе в программу. И да, конечно в query_chat стоит написать как раз тот запрос, который вернет нужные вам в алгоритме данные

Comment: @Mike он мне выводит только цифру, но не email, который был записан в сессию когда юзер логинится. Можете кодом скинуть?

Comment: но вы же сами выводите `$row_chat['user_id']` конечно это цифра. берите другое поле. И я не вижу где бы вы из сессии хоть что то доставали. Но сверятся с сессией в любом случае лучше по id

Comment: @Mike но у того кто написал сообщение и кто логиниться  разные id, хотя это один и тот же человек

Comment: тогда у вас в структуре БД что то не то. Не может быть у человека несколько разных id. id для того и используются, что бы уникально идентифицировать сущность.